# How to fire MQL query on button click

Tags: mql, freebase-acre

In my application layout, I have a button in left and a panel (div) in right. I want to show the number of topics added by a particular user in the right panel. For this purpose, I have written a MQL query which is working fine.

I am just not able to figure out the way to fire the query on button click event and display its result in the right side panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use some sort of ajax for this purpose. In the left pane, there is a list of users with hyperlinks. On click of these hyperlinks, a different pane with the results should open in the right pane. You do not need to fire mql query directly, just call a function on hyperlink click with username passed in it and further call a mql query and show up the results.